# Avoiding collisions on inserting manually incremented receipt number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a query that on every user purchase gets currently highest `receipt_counter` number from `receipts` table in order to create new receipt. `receipt_counter` is not unique in the table because it resets every year.

`receipt_counter` is just an integer that is used in generating `receipt_label` that looks like `"pos_id"-"receipt_counter"`.
There is a possibility that people can buy a product simultaneously on the same point of sale (`pos_id`).

Function that gets new `receipt_counter` looks like this:

```
SELECT (MAX(receipt_counter) + 1) as next_receipt_counter FROM receipts
```

The problem is when multiple people are buying a product simultaneously, which triggers generating new receipt (along with receipt number), sometimes a collision occurs (multiple people get same receipt number) because there is some delay between retrieving receipt counter and inserting new receipt into DB.

Is there a best practice to deal with this kind of problems? Do I need to use some kind of deadlock, or is my initial idea flawed and I need to change tactic for generating receipt counter all together?

EDIT: receipt_counter needs to be a sequential number without gaps.

Comment: can't you use a sequence to generate the `receipt_counter`?

Comment: If that delay is low, you can use LOCK TABLE. Then other user script will wait until you unlock that table, ie. order will be written to your DB.

Comment: **Do not try to implement sequence generators yourself, let the database do it.** See Lolo:s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is some delay between retrieving receipt counter and inserting new receipt into DB

You can change your software in order to instead or retrieving the ID without creating the actual receipt, it creates the receipt (with "pending" state or something like this) and then retrieve its ID. In the moment you currently create the receipt, you would just set its status to "active" or something.

Doing it this way you get rid of this time gap between getting and ID and storing the record, which in my point of view, is the main source of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate table for id only and enable auto_increment on that id column. Then add receipt in 2 steps - first add new record to id table, to receive back generated id. Then add actual receipt using received id. Then when you need just truncate table with id's when you want to reset the increment counter.

Comment: This solves my collision problem but the other problem is when one of simultaneous transactions fails, it will leave a "gap" in my `receipt_counter`

Answer (score 0):

Does the `receipt_counter` need to be an increasing number **without gaps**?

If an increasing large number with gaps is okay, how about generating a number out of the current date/time? If you go down to milliseconds or nanoseconds, the chance of a collision is pretty low.

For example:

`2013-11-13 13:08:15.012` -> `1113130815012`
*(I omitted the year because you said the number is reset every year anyway)*

Comment: It needs to be an increasing number without gaps